Permutation test in multiple linear regression, which way is correct?
I am fitting a linear regression model $$Y = \beta_0+ \beta_1 Z + \beta_2 X+\epsilon$$ Response $Y$ and covariate $X$ are continuous variables and $Z$ is a 0/1 dichotomous treatment group indicator, all are $N \times 1$ vectors. $\epsilon$ is a $N \times 1$ vector of normally distributed i.i.d. random errors with expectation 0 and unknown variance $\sigma^2$.
My goal is to obtain the joint distribution of 30 t-test statistics under the null hypothesis. This is to achive adjusted p-values for 30 correlated tests each corresponding to a separate response variabale $Y$. For this purpose, I want to obatin the permutation distribution of the t-test for the coefficient $\beta_1$. In permutations, which one of the following is correct:
(1)    Randomly permute $Y$, and obtain the distribution of $\beta_1$ accross 1000 permutations
(2)    Randomly permute $Z$, and obtain the distribution of $\beta_1$ accross 1000 permutations
(3)    Let $Z(X)$ be the vector of residuals from fitting $Z$ on $X$, and let $Y(X)$ be the residuals from fitting $Y$ on $X$. 
Then permute $Y(X)$ 1000 times and record the 1000 regression coefficients of $Z(X)$ when regressing $Y(X)$ on $Z(X)$.
(4)  Permute $Y(X)$ 1000 times and record the 1000 regression coefficients, where $Y(X)$ is regressed on $Z$. This would be same as comparing the means of the "X-adjusted values" of $Y$ in the 2 groups.
I would think (3) is the correct way as it preserves the relationships of $X$ to $Y$ and $Z$. Thus before permutation I should clear the effect of $X$ from both $Z$ and $Y$. But (4) also does not sound completely unreasonable to me. I cannot find a good reference where this is appropriately discussed.

It seems to me the answer must depend on what model you adopt for your regression and what your null hypothesis is.  Could you tell us what those might be?

@whuber: My null hypothesis is no treatment effect, i.e. $\beta_1=0$ in the regression model on the second line. I need the joint permutation distribution for the t-test for treatment effect $\beta_1$ w.r. to a large number of correlated outcomes to calculate family-wise error rate for t-tests (adjusted p-values).

"No treatment effect" might serve as a scientific statement of the null, but it's useless as a statistical statement without offering an explicit probability model for context.

I have now amended the regression model with a vector of normal errors $\epsilon$.

That works.  In (3), you might want to think about why you need any regressions involving your explanatory variables at all, given you don't posit any probability model for them.

@whuber: There is no model for the eplanatory variables. These are fixed vectors as usual. To calculate residuals is just a "technical trick". Replacing $Y$ and $Z$ by the correspoding residuals after adjusting for $X$ gives the same coefficient for $Z$ and same $SSE$ as the original model.

Permuting the Z residuals in (3) is more than a "technical trick:" it changes the variables you just claimed are "fixed."

I have changed the permutations to affect Y(X) in (3) and (4) although it does not matter which one we permute as in (3) and (4) we have only one response and one explanatory variable.

Great question. This paper compares various permutation tests for assessing the affect of a single predictor in a multivariable linear regression model:
An empirical comparison of permutation methods for tests of partial regression coefficients in a linear model

All of the methods compared were asymptotically equivalent in most situations.
Thus my personal preference is the approach where you simply permute the outcome, since it is the simplest.
However, for small sample sizes or if you have outliers in the main predictor of interest, then the "Reduced model residual permutation method" from their paper may be better.


when permuting the outcome, you are testing if the coefficient against the global null, not against the conditional hypothesis (i.e., is the coefficient not zero given all other features).

@Kozolovska: Yup.  In my experience, the price you pay is the test is more conservative compared to a conditional test, although the article I linked shows the approaches have asymptotically equivalent power.  The benefit of this approach is you only need to permute Y, and then from those perms you can test each feature in the model.  In contrast, the conditional permutation methods, require separate rounds of permutations for each feature in the model, thus higher computational cost.  If you only need 1 pvalue, this is no problem, but often I want pvalues for all features int he model.

@jarbet: I agree with Kozolovska. But when the interest is in one particular regression coefficient (say that of covariate X1), I think permuting the outcome is not a good option. In that case, we want to perturbe the relationship between the outcome Y and X1, but maintain the relationship between Y and other covariates W as they are, and also maintain the relationship between X1 and  W as they are. Perturbing the response would distort the original relationship between Y and W. The Freedman-Lane approach is computationally straightforward and solves this problem.

@MarkNh: Does the Freedman-Lane approach let you get pvalues for each predictor in the model with only one set of permutations, or do you have to do a separate set of permutations for each predictor? Just curious.

@jarbet: Freedman-Lane approach pertains only to a sigle coefficient. You need to run it separately for each of the expalnatory variables if needed.

@MarkNh Got it.  FWIW, I want to share an alternative bootstrap approach to permutation testing that let's you get confidence intervals and pvalues for each predictor from only one set of bootstrap replications:  https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/boot.pval/boot.pval.pdf. Check out the boot_summary function which works for glm and other models.

@jarbet: Thanks. Bootsrap mimics the sampling distribution of a statistic. But my goal is to simulate the joint distribution of several test statistics under the null hypothesis. This is to achive adjusted p-values for correlated tests. I think I need to use permuation distribution rather than bootstrap to achieve this.

@jarbet: My comment above is not accurate. Indeed, there is a clever way to twist bootstrap to prodece distributions of test statistics under the null hypothesis by Hall and Wilson (1991, Two Guidelines for Bootstrap Hypothesis Testing, Biometrics). This is probably what you suggested and it may be a good alternative to the permutation approach!

Inspired by the refrence provided by @jarbet, I studied the issue a bit deeper and as suggested (for example) by   Anderson and Robinson(2008) Permutation Tests for Linear Models
the preferred approach appears to be the Freedman-Lane method described below as method (5). Recall that in my initial post $Z$ is the variable of interest and $X$ is a nuisance variable to be adjusted for:
(5) (Freedman-Lane method)(a)  Calculate residuals $Y(X)$ (see my earlier item 3)  $\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ $and also the corresponding fitted values  $FittedY(X)$=$Y$-$Y(X)$. (b) Permute the residuals $Y(X)$, and obtain the permuted residuals $Y^*(X)$.(c) Regress  $Y^*(X)$+$FittedY(X)$ on the original unpermuted variables $Z$ and $X$ $\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ $and obtain coefficient for $X$ and the desired statistic (for example t-test) (d) repeat items b,c 1000 times and obtain the permutation distribution of the statistic.
Actually this makes sense. We are shuffling only the part of  $Y$ that is not related to $X$, so the effect of $X$ on $Z$ and $Y$ is not perturbed. But it is still unclear to me why this approach is better than approach (3) in my original post which also does not perturbe the effect of $X$ on $Z$ and $Y$. I assume the difference is not huge.
